# django rest framework: Get nested representation of child elements

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a tree of items which reference each other as parent/children. Now I want to serialize the children as nested objects to minimize the requests. My problem is that I can't initiate the serializer class from within itself (obviously)... Is there a way to do this?

(I will fix the recursion issue, please don't mind about that)

Model:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    dashboard = models.ForeignKey(Dashboard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Dashboard"))
    config = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Configuration"))
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Item", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="children", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Parent"))
    previous = models.OneToOneField("Item", related_name="next", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=link_previous_item_on_delete, verbose_name=_("Previous"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializer:

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # This will obviously not work:
    children = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("name", "dashboard", "config", "children")
```

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Thanks a lot, I somehow missed that the `depth` attribute would help me.